# React Native architecture for big projects - Any ideas?

Tags: react-native, architecture, monorepo

We are working on a monorepo architecture with React Native, we have two apps and a lot of packages inside it, this solves our problem for a long time but our team is growing fast, and we'll probably have a lot of people work on a single repo.

I want to know if someone already faces this "issue" and how you manage to solve it? Microservice? Each package should be a lib and have its own repo?

Can you guys share your experience?